# Pass EFS ID to OpsWorks via Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks, amazon-efs

We are working on a cloudformation template in AWS. However, we can't find a way on how to pass the EFS ID to OpsWorks so that it can be mounted in the OpsWorks' Instances.

For EC2 instances, they can pass the EFS ID to a bash command or shell script embedded as user-data or adding it in an auto-scale configuration.

We also tried adding the "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" meta data in the opsworks instance but it seems like it will only work for "AWS::EC2::Instance".

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, we just need to set a custom JSON on the stack itself then reference the EFS ID.